# login no entra como admin

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy creando un login para administradores, pero no puedo entrar si soy admin, sin embargo si no existe el usuario o no es admin va bien. Este es el código:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
                        <!--my_account_admin.php-->
                        <label for="adminname"><b>Nombre de administrador:</b></label><br><br>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre de admin" required id="adminname" name="adminname"/><br><br>
                        <label for="password"><b>Contraseña:</b></label><br><br>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required id="password" name="password"/><br><br>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Recuerdame</label><br><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Aceptar" name="aceptar"/>
                        <?php
                            if(isset($_POST['aceptar'])){
                                $adminname=$_POST["adminname"];
                                $password=$_POST["password"];
                                $cuenta="";
                                require('includes/config.php');
                                try{
                                    $sql=$db->prepare('SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username=:adminname AND password=:password');
                                    $sql->execute(array(
                                        ':adminname'=>$adminname,
                                        ':password'=>$password
                                    ));
                                    $row=$sql->fetch();
                                    if($row){
                                        $cuenta="";
                                        $sql=$db->prepare('SELECT username,cuenta FROM users WHERE username=:adminname AND cuenta=:cuenta');
                                        $sql->execute(array(
                                            ':adminname'=>$adminname,
                                            ':cuenta'=>$cuenta
                                        ));
                                        if($cuenta=='admin'){
                                            session_start();
                                            $_SESSION['adminname']=$adminname;
                                            echo $_SESSION['adminname'];
                                        }elseif($cuenta!='admin'){
                                            echo "El usuario existe, pero no es Administrador.";
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        echo "No existe este usuario.";
                                    }
                                }catch(PDOException $e){
                                    echo $e->getMessage();
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        <input type="reset" value="Cancelar"/><br><br>
                        <a href="#">¿Has perdido tu contraseña?</a><br><br>
                    </form>
```

Comment: En tu select deberías primero comprobar primero si existe el usuario y SU contraseña, pero lo comparas con $cuenta que su valor inicial es = "";

Comment: en el primer select no compruebo la cuenta, es en el segundo

Comment: ya,ya, pero deberías comprobar si el usuario que está introduciendo los datos, realmente existe, es decir, para saber si existe, lanzas contra la base de datos el usuario y la contraseña que te han puesto en el formulario, en caso de existir,  entonces ya compruebas su tipo de cuenta, pero no al revés.

Comment: @EduBw eso hago primero user y pass y luego cuenta de ese user

Comment: Explícanos un poco la lógica si es posible. yo cuando veo tantos `if` y tantos `SELECT`, me digo que algún problema de diseño o de lógica hay para que el código sea tan repetitivo. Aplicando el [método del patito de goma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Método_de_depuración_del_patito_de_goma) te das cuenta muchas veces de que estás errando en el diseño, y arrastrar esos errores luego pasa factura en todo el sistema que estás desarrollando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya lo he resuelto, gracias a l@s chic@s del chat:

```
if(isset($_POST['aceptar'])){
                                $adminname=$_POST["adminname"];
                                $password=$_POST["password"];
                                require('includes/config.php');
                                try{
                                    $sql=$db->prepare('SELECT cuenta FROM users WHERE username=:adminname AND password=:password');
                                    $sql->execute(array(
                                        ':adminname'=>$adminname,
                                        ':password'=>$password
                                    ));
                                    $row=$sql->fetch();
                                    if($row){
                                        if($row['cuenta']=='admin'){
                                            session_start();
                                            $_SESSION['adminname']=$adminname;
                                            echo $_SESSION['adminname'];
                                        }else{
                                            echo "El usuario existe, pero no es Administrador.";
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        echo "No existe este usuario.";
                                    }
                                }catch(PDOException $e){
                                    echo $e->getMessage();
                                }
                            }
```